# Why JMeter failures marks as KO?

Tags: jmeter

When I open JMeter dashboard I can see success in column `OK` and failure in `KO` column. According to [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=KO) KO is equals to OK

> "KO" is the equivalent to the meaning & abbreviation of the letters meaning "OK"

or is it French [informal acronym](https://linguaphiles.livejournal.com/6180251.html) ?

> I've noticed that the acronym KO in French and Italian informal communication can mean simply "not OK"

I saw different questions about [changing KO label](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/how-to-customize-jmeter-dashboard-report-generated-in-jmeter-v3-1) to failure.

Why JMeter refers errors as `KO`, is there another meaning in performance testing? or is it using positive thinking where failures are OK too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s mainly because contributors of this dashboard (french committers partly) thought KO meant not OK .

Feel free to contribute a fixing patch.

Comment: I like the acronym ,maybe just need to add a short explanation

Answer (score 7):

It's not only that French contributors *thought*: in several European languages (French and Italian included) KO actually *used* as **not OK**. For example "*Je suis KO*" means "*I am not OK*". You can see a discussion about this word [here](https://linguaphiles.livejournal.com/6180251.html)

From there, I think as early as 90s, or maybe even earlier, the word migrated into software, and I've seen it in several applications, since it's very convenient:

- To English speakers KO is short of knock-out in boxing, so can easily be connected something that is broken or busted out - like request result in this case is.
- Both words - OK and KO - are second short way to describe status (shortest way is V and X)
- They take the same space, and thus will not cause columns to misalign in any font (where's any different 2 letter words could, depending on font).

You also can change that: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28744/jmeter-dashboard-report-how-to-change-ko-to-failed-in-pie-chart-of-summary

Comment: Can you share which applications uses KO?

Comment: Hard to remember (never thought of it as something unusual I guess)... I want to say I saw it in some IBM tool(?), which is partially confirmed by [this](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/french_to_english/computers%3A_software/1453286-ko.html#3397534) link, although I remember it being a return code, rather than an error message. And it was definitely used in some older Mercury products, either loadrunner, or winrunner. Unfortunately couldn't confirm. Hard to search for KO - mostly brings irrelevant results.

Comment: @user7294900 my engineering school has always used OK/KO for automated testing results. I however have to agree that it can easily be confused - if you are not used to it or tired.

Comment: @user7294900 SonarQube does

Answer (score 0):

From JMeter 5.4 KO header renamed to [FAIL](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64824)

> KO does not seem to be clear for some users:
> So name it FAIL instead