# How to remove check_user_activity from Jmeter reports and How to change KO to fail in stastastics table?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I am using JMeter dashboard for reporting. I want;

1. To remove Check_User_Activity part from it
2. Need to rename KO as Fail in statistics table, I checked C:\JMeter\bin\report-template\content\js and try to search the KO but not found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change the label "KO" open the file apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/report-template/content/js/dashboard.js.fmkr and change the value

[image]

Following links could be useful

1. changing the [label](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/how-to-customize-jmeter-dashboard-report-generated-in-jmeter-v3-1)
2. [Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201477/why-jmeter-failures-marks-as-ko) for labeling failures are KO

**check_user_activity** is coming from your sampler labels. You need to configure the labels accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ! But I have already changed the KO to Fail on pie graph and by already changed KO to fail on C:\JMeter\lib\ext\org\apache\jmeter\resources\message.properties but this is not displaying in statistical table where I want it exactly.

Comment: I could not find a property in the installation directory. Checked the JMeter source and noted following /apache-jmeter-5.3/src/core/src/main/resources/org/apache/jmeter/resources/messages.properties:981:reportgenerator_summary_total=Total. Can you change the value in the message.properties file, build the source and give a try?

Comment: Not sure if this is coming from a jar file. Let me check and get back to you.