# Why explicitly capturing constexpr variable doesn't work while not capturing it works

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-bug

I wrote the following code that has two lambdas. One of them explicitly captures `i` while the other doesn't. Note `i` is constexpr so we don't need to capture it explicitly.

My question is why `func(lambda2)` doesn't compile while `func(lambda)` does? Note `lambda` doesn't explicitly capture `i` while `lambda2` has `i` in its capture list. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xTnvnsxz9)

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto func(T c) {
    constexpr auto k = c; 
    return k;
};


int main() {
    
    constexpr int i = 0;
    
    constexpr auto lambda = []()constexpr { constexpr int j = i; return j; };  //compiles
    constexpr auto lambda2 = [i]()constexpr { constexpr int j = i; return j; };//compiles
   
    constexpr auto a = func(lambda); //compiles as expected

    
    constexpr auto b = func(lambda2); //this doesn't compile why?
    
}
```

Clang says:

```
error: constexpr variable 'k' must be initialized by a constant expression
    3 |     constexpr auto k = c; 
      |                    ^   ~
/home/insights/insights.cpp:18:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<(lambda at /home/insights/insights.cpp:13:30)>' requested here
   18 |     constexpr auto b = func(lambda2); //this doesn't compile why?
      |                        ^
/home/insights/insights.cpp:3:24: note: function parameter 'c' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression
    3 |     constexpr auto k = c; 
      |                        ^
/home/insights/insights.cpp:3:24: note: in call to '(lambda at /home/insights/insights.cpp:13:30)(c)'
/home/insights/insights.cpp:2:23: note: declared here
    2 | constexpr auto func(T c) {
      |                       ^
```

Comment: IANALL, but I think your `constexpr auto k = c;` will fail to be a proper constexpr.  If you just remove the `constexpr` so that the body of the template function is under the function constexpr instead of having another constexpr scope (that'll fail to be constexpr), you should be fine.  I leave it to a language-lawyer can cite chapter-and-verse from the standard, and use the standard-ese terminology.

Comment: Do you want to (`constexpr`) copy the lambda, or call it `constexpr auto k = c();`?

Comment: Function parameters are NOT `constexpr`, so `k = c` would use non `constexpr` `c`. with capture, the member has to be copied (but it is not `constexpr`), whereas captureless lambda won't use `this` at all, and is still viable in `constexpr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to understand how exactly the standard allows one to work but not the other. Also I am aware that function parameters are not constexpr. But this is for academic purposes only. Also note that clang still rejects the program of we call the `c` like in `constexpr auto k= c();` while gcc and msvc accepts it. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y3PMefabh) *I'll ask a separate question for that.*

Comment: Simplified case [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TfKrcor6v) (without lambda).

Comment: I'm adding a [tag:compiler-bug] tag because it looks like an accepts-invalid bug. There is clearly lvalue-to-rvalue conversion here, which would disqualify a constant expression ([expr.const]), however, compilers don't check for this and only fail when a member was accessed.

Comment: See [LLVM Issue 83712](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/83712) and [GCC Bug 114219](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114219).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar, but simpler version of the code that doesn't compile:

```
constexpr auto func(int a) {
    constexpr auto b = a;
    return b;
};

int main() {
    constexpr int x = 1;
    constexpr int y = func(x);
}
```

Here, because `x` is `constexpr`, it's ok to read the value of `x` within the initialization of the `constexpr` variable `y`.

However, that's not good enough, because not only does `y` need to have a constant expression as its initializer, but so does `b`, which is also declared `constexpr`. And this is where the issue arises. If `b` had not been declared `constexpr`, then the code would be fine.

In order for `constexpr auto b = ...;` to be valid, the compiler has to be able to evaluate it as a constant expression in the context where it appears—not the larger enclosing context in which `func` is called. In the context where the initialization of `b` appears, the value of `a` is not known until runtime. `func` may be called in both constant expressions and non-constant expressions. So the check that `b` is a constant expression fails.

In the OP's program, it's very similar. `lambda2`, which captures `i`, is of a closure type having a data member of type `const int` ([[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10.sentence-2)). When `func` is called, the statement

```
constexpr auto k = c;
```

in its body is instantiated, with `c` being a function parameter of that closure type. At this point, the initialization of `k` has to be checked as a constant expression in the context where it appears, not the context of the enclosing constant evaluation. The initialization uses the copy constructor of the closure type, which is defaulted ([[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#15)) and thus performs a memberwise-copy. It must therefore read the `const int` member of the function parameter `c`.

To give a bit more detail:

[[dcl.constexpr]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6) states that "In any `constexpr` variable declaration, the full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression". Let's apply this to the declaration of `k`. In order for it to be a constant expression, it has to be a core constant expression that satisfies some other conditions ([[expr.const]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#14)). [expr.const]/5 gives the conditions for an expression *E* to be a core constant expression. In this case *E* is the *init-declarator* of `k`.

When `k` is initialized, the `const int` data member of `c` will be read, as discussed above. This is an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. [[expr.const]/5.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.9) states that an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not allowed in a core constant expression *E* except when applied to either

- a non-volatile glvalue that refers to an object that is usable in constant expressions, or
- a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of *E*

The second bullet is clearly not satisfied: the lifetime of the `const int` member of `c` does not start within the evaluation of *E* (*i.e.* the *init-declarator* of `k`); it starts beforehand, when the function is called. As for the first bullet, a function parameter is not usable in constant expressions because it can never be both "constant-initialized" and "potentially-constant" ([[expr.const]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4)). In particular, a function parameter of scalar or reference type cannot satisfy [[expr.const]/2.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.1) and a function parameter of class type cannot satisfy [[expr.const]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#3).

(By the way, even in a `consteval` function, a function parameter's value still isn't a constant expression, despite the fact that a `consteval` function can only be called during constant evaluation. There is no fundamental reason why it can't be supported in the `consteval` case, but if it were allowed then it would create implementation difficulties and turn almost every `consteval` function into an implicit template.)

Comment: This doesn't explain why `lambda` which doesn't capture `i` works. I want to know how the standard allows `lambda` but not `lambda2` .

Comment: Also the example you gave is not actually similar. Lambdas are separate c++ constructs and have additional rules that have to be followed. So comparing it with a non-lambda example is questionable. For example the `lambda` works but not `lambda2`.

Comment: @Alan If there's no capture, then there's no data member that gets accessed during copy construction. I believe I made it clear in my answer that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the `const int` data member is the issue.

Comment: @BrianBi Sorry but can you tell me why is it that when there is no capture there isn't a data member. I mean `lambda` is using `i` in its body so how can it use `i` in its body without capturing it(like without having a data member)

Comment: @Alan One of the links to the standard that I provided explains when data members are declared in the closure type. If your question is "why am I allowed to use that variable without capturing it", that should be posted as a new question.

Comment: I think you're 100% right. It doesn't matter whether you're effectively using an empty class, there is clearly lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Looks like a compiler bug to me. Oddly enough, all major three compilers accept-invalid here and only start complaining once you pass around non-empty classes (or non-captureless lambdas).

Comment: See [LLVM Issue 83712](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/83712) and [GCC Bug 114219](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114219).