# Is lvalue to rvalue conversion not applied on empty class object passed by value

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr

I wrote the following program where if a class have a non-static data member then when an object of that type is passed as argument by value, then it can't be used in a constexpr context. After searching for the issue on the web, I came across this [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114219) where some user said something like  when the class is empty, then no lvalue to rvalue transformation is applied which is why the `A` in the below example works but not `B`. But then other user is saying that this isn't the case.

**I want to know** how exactly the standard allows the empty class case to work but not the non-empty class case. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dPfv6bbPK)

```
struct A {
    static constexpr int value = 42;
};
struct B
{
    static constexpr int value = 42;
    int mem{};
};

constexpr int f(A a) { return A::value; }
constexpr int f(B b) { return B::value; } 

int main() {
    A a; 
    constexpr int aconst = f(a); //works in all compilers

    B b;
    constexpr int bconst = f(b); //fails in all compilers, why?
}
```

Gcc says:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:18:31: error: the value of 'b' is not usable in a constant expression
   18 |     constexpr int bconst = f(b); //fails in all compilers, why?
      |                               ^
<source>:17:7: note: 'b' was not declared 'constexpr'
   17 |     B b;
      |
```

Basically I want to know if the claim that lvalue to rvalue transformation is bypassed in case of empty class case is true or not. And if it is, where/how exactly according to the standard.

Comment: There's a general rule that a constexpr function can run at compile-time even if it has an non-constexpr reference parameter, as long as it's unused. And this is just a manifestation of that, apparently. (Here the function is the copy constructor.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[dcl.init.general]/14](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#14)

> The initialization that occurs [...] as well as in argument passing [...] is called *copy-initialization*.

The semantics of the copy-initializations in the two function calls in the question are governed by [[dcl.init.general]/16.6.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.6.2):

> Otherwise, if the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]).
>   Then:
>
>   - If overload resolution is successful, the selected constructor is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or *expression-list* as its argument(s).
>   - [...]
> - [...]

The initialization of the parameter `a` from the argument `a`, or the parameter `b` from the argument `b`, is by constructor. In these cases the copy constructors are used (I hope this is obvious enough that I don't need to explain it).

Since `A` and `B` don't have user-declared copy constructors, [[class.copy.ctor]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#6) applies:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a non-explicit one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defaulted ([dcl.fct.def]).
> The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor ([depr.impldec]).

The semantics of an implicitly declared copy constructor are given by [[class.copy.ctor]/14](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#14).

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class `X` performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. [...] The order of initialization is the same as the order of initialization of bases and members in a user-defined constructor (see [class.base.init]). Let `x` be either the parameter of the constructor or, for the move constructor, an xvalue referring to the parameter. Each base or non-static data member is copied/moved in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> - if the member is an array, each element is direct-initialized with the corresponding subobject of `x`;
> - if a member `m` has rvalue reference type `T&&`, it is direct-initialized with `static_cast<T&&>(x.m)`;
> - otherwise, the base or member is direct-initialized with the corresponding base or member of `x`.
>
> Virtual base class subobjects shall be initialized only once by the implicitly-defined copy/move constructor (see [class.base.init]).

Since `A` has neither bases nor non-static data members, its copy constructor does nothing. `B` on the other hand has a single non-static data member of type `int`, so according to the above, its implicit copy constructor direct-initializes `mem` from the `mem` member of the object being copied, which is a const lvalue of type `int` (because the parameter to the copy constructor has type `const B&`).

The semantics of a direct-initialization of an `int` from a const lvalue of type `int` are given by [[dcl.init.general]/16.9](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.9):

> - [...]
> - Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression. A standard conversion sequence ([conv]) is used to convert the initializer expression to a prvalue of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered. If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed. When initializing a bit-field with a value that it cannot represent, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined. [...]

The destination type is `int`, so we must form a standard conversion sequence from an lvalue of `const int` to a prvalue of `int`. The standard conversion that can accomplish this is the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. See [[conv.lval]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#1) (footnotes omitted):

> A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be converted to a prvalue. If `T` is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If `T` is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of `T`. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is `T`.

Lvalue-to-rvalue conversions are applied when the rules of the language either explicitly require them to be performed, or when the rules of the language call for a standard conversion sequence to be performed from some source type to some destination type and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ends up being a necessary step in that standard conversion sequence. The copy-initialization of an empty class type such as `A` from the same type is not one of these situations since, based on the above, it is specified to have the behaviour of calling a constructor (not performing a standard conversion) and there is no other rule that demands the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in such a case. However, copying a glvalue of a scalar type always entails an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: Before marking this answer as correct can you tell me why when we change `B b;` to `constexpr B b;` the program starts compiling? I mean even then the same logic is applied and the copy ctor does the same thing(copies `mem`). So lvalue to rvalue happens in that case also but then it compiles there.

Comment: @Alan An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is allowed in a constant expression when it's applied to a variable that is "usable in constant expressions". See http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.9.1

Answer (score -1):

When you pass a scalar type by-value to a function, then the initialization of the function parameter will directly involve an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to read the value of the passed object.

When you pass a class type by-value to a function, then you are actually initializing the function parameter with a call to the classes copy constructor.

In the call to the copy constructor the source object is taken *by-reference*, so there is no immediate lvalue-to-rvalue conversion there.

An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion will happen only if *inside* the copy constructor a (scalar) non-static data member of the class is copied (which again requires obtaining its value).

Comment: But if we change `B b;` to `constexpr B b;` then program starts compiling. Why is that? I mean then also the copy ctor is do memberwise copy.

Comment: @Alan Because lvalue-to-rvalue conversions are only forbidden in a constant expression if the object on which the conversion is applied neither has its lifetime started during the expression evaluation, nor is _usable in constant expressions_, which `constexpr` variables are however.

Comment: @Alan From a more practical perspective: If the class is empty it has no state, so there is nothing "unknown" about it at compile-time. If the variable is `constexpr`, then its value is required to be known at compile-time as well, regardless of its state.

Comment: Ok I have seen the same explanation in other SO posts also but I want to see exactly where the standard mentions this(like empty class has no state and nothing unknown about it). I want this question to be a canonical for all those questions. So it should cite exact standard references. Because this seems common SO question.

Comment: @Alan Unfortunately the reasoning the standard is a bit complex. It doesn't consider empty classes specifically. The standard does not make an attempt at explaining this practical reasoning, although it is specified exactly in such a way that it will be the outcome.

Comment: @Alan Instead you have to start with https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.8, and a handful of paragraphs earlier in [expr.const] to define "usable in constant expressions". Then to see whether there is a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion you need multiple iterations through [dcl.init] and [class.copy.ctor] and finally will (only for scalars) end with https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.9 requiring a standard conversion sequence which per definition in [conv] can include an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. I don't really feel like writing all of it down.

Comment: @user17732522 I feel this answer is rushed. You should take your time and add the relevant references and quote them in the answer.

Comment: @user17732522 **This answer does not explain the problem in a language-lawyer'ed way.** I am already aware of the layman's explanation. I want an authoritative answer.